# Center elements vertically according to a manually assigned center position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have parent div larger and inside that I have a set of images. Each image has a value called 'top-to-center' and it is assigned in pixels. A representation is given below.

```
********** --
*        *  }  <--- 'top-to-center' value( example: 100px )
*    X   * --
*        *  
*        *   
*        *  
**********
```

And parent div is larger one and set of images which has different top-to-center values must be aligned along the horizontal center line of the parent DIV. For an example the 'X' point of above image must be overlap the center horizontal line of the parent DIV. Each images must be aligned along the parent horizontal center line by overlapping each image's manually assigned center points. Please can someone help me to solve this. I tried to achieve this various js scripts and nothing was successful!

Here is the HTML:

```
    <ul id="sortable" style="display: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right:  auto;" class="ui-sortable">
        <li style="display: none; position: relative;" id="initialItem"  class="ui-sortable-handle ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" data-id="26" id="comp-0" style="height: 56.25px; width: 84.375px; margin: 28.125px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteButton" style="display: none;" onclick="remover(0)">x</a>S</li><li  class="ui-state-default" data-id="26" id="comp-1" style="height: 56.25px; width:  84.375px; margin: 28.125px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteButton" style="display: none;" onclick="remover(1)">x</a>S</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" data-id="26" id="comp-2" style="height: 56.25px; width: 84.375px; margin: 28.125px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteButton" style="display: none;" onclick="remover(2)">x</a>S</li>   
    </ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript :

```
//get database information of components

var findItem = function(id){
    var item;
    var obj = JSON.parse(php_vars);
    for(var i=0; obj.length > i; i++){
      if( parseFloat(obj[i].id) == id ){
        item = obj[i];
      }
    }
    return item;
    }
    //object of elements - components array has IDs of elements
      var options = {
          components: [1,2,6,4,2] //example
      }
    //loop through components
    for(var i=0; options.components.length > i; i++){
        var component = findItem(options.components[i]);
        var center_value = component.top_to_center;
        //get center of the parent div
        var board_center = parseFloat($('#board').height()/2);
        //assign margin top and align to center
        $('#comp-'+i).css('margin-top', board_center - center_value);
    }
    //...
    //further code???
};
```

Comment: post your code. Not possible to help without seeing code

Comment: thank you! I have added the code.